# Kivy MDBoxLayout keeps increasing width automatically when running, raised [CRITICAL] [Clock] Warning

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

When I add a ChatBubble in my app, that ChatBubble will automatically increase its width for each millisecond although its size is already given.

The issue shown in the command prompt is

> [CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the
> next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration
> attribute

I'm trying to find a way to make ChatBubble work normally like any other chatbox like Messenger or Whatsapp, I also tried to find the problem in my code for hours but couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

I converted the part of the problem code into a small app for you to see the issue easier.

.py file

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, DictProperty, OptionProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
#from components.label import PLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout, BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ChatBubble(MDBoxLayout):
    send_by_user = BooleanProperty()
    msg = StringProperty()
    time = StringProperty()

class Container(MDBoxLayout):
    def on_button_click(self):
        self.on_start()
    def on_start(self):
        self.c = ChatBubble()
        self.c.send_by_user = True
        self.c.msg = "hello world"
        self.c.time = "11:22AM"
        self.ids["lst"].add_widget(self.c)
        
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("chat_bubble.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
Container:
 
<Container>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: lst
            spacing: 5
            padding: [0, 10, 0, 10]
    Button:
        text: "Click"
        on_press:
            root.on_button_click()

<ChatBubble>:
    id: chtbld
    md_bg_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 60
    adaptive_height: True
    width: root.width
    padding: [10, 0, 10, 0]
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDBoxLayout:
        height: msg_content.height + timed.height + 10
        width: msg_content.width + wid1.width + wid2.width
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1} if chtbld.send_by_user == True else {'left': 1}
        radius: [10, 10, (1, -5), 10] if self.pos_hint == {'right': 1} else [10, 10, 10, (1, -5)]
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark if root.send_by_user else app.theme_cls.primary_color
        Spacer:
            id: wid1
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            height: msg_content.height + tc.height + wid3.height
            width: msg_content.width

            MDLabel:
                id: msg_content
                text: root.msg
                width: tc.width if self.texture_size[0] < tc.width else self.texture_size[0]
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                size_hint_y: None
                text_size: chtbld.width-30 if self.width >= chtbld.width-30 else None, None
                halign: 'left'
                color: app.theme_cls.opposite_bg_normal

            MDBoxLayout:
                id: tc
                size_hint_y: None
                height: timed.height
                width: timed.width + 3
                spacing: 3
                MDLabel:
                    id: timed
                    text: root.time
                    size: self.texture_size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_size: 9
                    bold: True
                    halign: 'right'
                    text_size: None, None
                    color: [.8, .8, .8, 1]
            Spacer:
                id: wid3
                height: 5
        Spacer:
            id: wid2

<Spacer@Widget>:
    id: wid
    width: 5
    size_hint: None, None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is due to the inter-dependencies of inner widgets (especially the `MDLabel` with `id: msg_content`, `MDBoxLayout` with `id: tc`, `MDLabel` with `id: timed`) in the field of `size`, `texture_size` etc. and not handling those properties separately.

Disabling the `size_hint` before setting custom `size` seems to work.

```py
            ...
            MDBoxLayout:
                id: tc
                size_hint: None, None # To set custom size.
                height: timed.height
                width: timed.width + 3
                pos_hint: {'right': 1} # To hold itself and text on right.
                spacing: 3
                MDLabel:
                    id: timed
                    text: root.time
                    size_hint: None, None # To set custom size.
                    size: self.texture_size
                    font_size: 9
                    bold: True
                    halign: 'right' # This wouldn't work since its size is set to its texture_size.
                    ...
```

You should also change the `pos_hint` value as `{'left': 1}` (which is an invalid key, may be `{"x" : 0}` is what you want).

---

However I found your design somewhere over complicated. There's a sample example ([`messenger.py`](https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/3fa263ef8a67c7c3f2aee2c99c4ce6ed)) by one of the kivy's core developer tshirtman, you may look into.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of behavior usually means that the sizing of your widgets is getting into an infinite loop of inter-dependent widget sizes. You can stop that loop by changing the `width` calculation of your `MDLabel` with the `id` of `msg_content` from:

```
width: tc.width if self.texture_size[0] < tc.width else self.texture_size[0]
```

to:

```
width: self.texture_size[0]
```

This may not be what you want, but it seems that the dependency of `msg_content` on`tc` is causing the looping.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for your help, I will take the rest from here.

Comment: Perhaps this will not fix the issue (at least not in my case) completely considering the case where the user (end user) send null text, as happened in ordinary messenger.

Comment: @ApuCoder I know, but based on John's answer I have managed to find out the bug. It comes from "+ 3" in tc.width: timed.width + 3 (just delete it and keep "timed.width" only). Still don't really know how does this happens. I'm working on it now since it's leading to many new issues